# How to load the properties from application.properties in Mockito test

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, mocking, mockito

I am trying to write a unit test case to test the method, but I encounter a problem.

here is the sample code:

**MyService1**

```
@Service
public class MyService1 {

    @Autowired
    private ServiceProperties serviceProperties;

    public void getMyLanguage(){
        String language =  serviceProperties.getLocale().getLanguage();
        printSomething(language);
    }

    private void printSomething(String input){
        System.out.print("your current language is " + input);
    }
}
```

**ServiceProperties**

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;

import java.util.Locale;

@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "conversation")
public class ServiceProperties {

    private ServiceProperties(){};

    private Locale locale;

    public Locale getLocale(){

        return locale;

    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
conversation.locale=en_US
```

Here is my test case:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyService1Test {
    @Mock
    private ServiceProperties serviceProperties;

    @InjectMocks
    private MyService1 myService1;

    @Test
    public void getMyLanguage(){
        when(serviceProperties.getLocale().getLanguage()).thenReturn("EN");
        myService1.getMyLanguage();
        verify(myService1).getMyLanguage();
    }
}
```

the test will trigger nullpointerexception, because the properties for locale are not loaded in test, if I don't want to start the server(use @SpringBootTest annotation) to load the context, is there any way to solve this problem, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is at this line:

```
when(serviceProperties.getLocale().getLanguage()).thenReturn("EN");
```

Because `serviceProperties` is mocked, `serviceProperties.getLocale()` is equal to `null`. So you get `NullPointerException` when `serviceProperties.getLocale().getLanguage()` is called.

One workaround would be as follows:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyService1Test {
    @Mock
    private ServiceProperties serviceProperties;
    @InjectMocks
    private MyService1 myService1;

    @Test
    public void getMyLanguage(){
        when(serviceProperties.getLocale()).thenReturn(new Locale("EN"));
        myService1.getMyLanguage();
        verify(myService1).getMyLanguage();
    }
}
```

Comment: But this does not in fact answer the question, I have a similar situation with more than one service properties that could change in application.porperties. new Locale("EN") is not reading from properties but hardcoding it in test. What is the minimum that's needed to load application.properties in a unit test?

Answer (score 0):

Field injection is not convenient for testing. You can use constructor injection

```
@Service
public class MyService {


    private final ServiceProperties serviceProperties;

    @Autowired
    public MyService(ServiceProperties serviceProperties) {
        this.serviceProperties = serviceProperties;
    }
    //...
}
```

And then you will be able to inject mocks before each test

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyService1Test {
    @Mock
    private ServiceProperties serviceProperties;

    private MyService1 myService1;

    @Before
    public void createService(){
        myService1 = new MyService1(serviceProperties);
    }
}
```